# Is FAT 32-bit version ok for Linux?

Tags: fat32

I understand this may be a dumb question but I just realized my main SSD is a FAT 32-bit version - I installed Ubuntu a while ago. Is this partition format ok or would another one work better with Linux?

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to using this format?

Thanks!

EDIT: by my main SSD I mean the main HDD where Ubuntu is installed.

EDIT2: To clarify this is the drive https://i.stack.imgur.com/32li8.png and "/dev/sdb1 vfat 523248 4744 518504 1% /boot/efi" - and I ask this becasue I got a notification from Dropbox saying my drive is not compatible with the new Dropbox formats and will stop syncing in November and I've read that Dropbox only accepts ext4 and I had to check and my SSD says what it says. So I am confused is it FAT32 or lime someone explained it only uses FAT32 to boot but Ubuntu is installed on ext4? I am confused.

Comment: [Unless you have a really old installation of Ubuntu, it is not possible to install it on a FAT partition.](https://superuser.com/a/783113/418736) The standard for Ubuntu partitions is ext4 nowadays, at least for normal home usage.

Comment: fat32 only allowed 8.3 character filenames (without dirty tricks), doesn't allow the storage of file permissions (beyond 4 bits) so I think it's a bad idea.  It's chosen usually as most things will read it for devices used to 'transfer' files between devices. If you care about your file-system's metadata (which can't be stored on it), you'll avoid it for files that matter.

Comment: If you have a new UEFI system, UEFI boots from FAT32, but Ubuntu is installed in ext4 by default. Or the live installer is a FAT32 partition or hybrid DVD/flash drive image that UEFI can boot.

Comment: This is what I get "/dev/sdb1                   vfat        523248      4744    518504   1% /boot/efi" - so it is vfat? What is the difference? I have to mention I have Ubuntu 18.04 and the disk is encrypted and everything works just fine so...I was just wondering if there is a problem with the drive format.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CswZNZd.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intsalling ubuntu along side windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066320/intsalling-ubuntu-along-side-windows-10)

Comment: @karel Not sure it answers my question. Like I showcased my partition says it is fat and I even got a warning from Dropbox saying it will only support ext4 from now on and my drive is not ext4 so it will stop syncing from November. So I am trying to solve that mystery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any safer Dropbox alternatives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496170/are-there-any-safer-dropbox-alternatives) and [Recommendation for Cloud Sync Storage Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020019/recommendation-for-cloud-sync-storage-solution)

Comment: @karel  Well no, because I am still wondering about the FAT32 type. Do I have that formatting or is that only for UEFI booting and the system is installed on ext4?

Comment: The system is installed on an ext4 partition like the answer to the linked duplicate question says.

Comment: Ok karel if that's the answer thank you very much!